# Updating email address by adding '@live.com' to the end

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to update a table of email list by adding '@live.com" at the end, as some users forget to put this suffix for their email address. For example, they input something like "imsuperman" while it should be 'imsuperman@live.com'.

I'm using codeigniter but got stuck at the following code:

```
        $this->db->select('email, username');
        $user=$this->db->get('user');

        foreach ($user->result() as $row):

        $to_username=$row->username;

        //load email address
        $to_email_raw=$row->email;

        if(strpos($to_email_raw, '@') !==false)
        {
            $to_email=$to_email_raw;
        }
        else
        {
            $to_email=$to_email_raw.'@live.com';
        }

        endforeach;
```

I've so far changed the email address for each row. Any advice on how I should update the table next?

Thanks,

Comment: I've never used CI, but is there an `$this->db->update` function? I'm sure you could just Google for "CodeIgniter update table".

Comment: a suggestion. why don't you add the `@live.com` when they input it using javascript. you don't need to update your table each time that way

Comment: but the downside of both ways is that you are assuming that the user has an email address with `@live.com`

Comment: yes, I also did that, but now I need to update the table which already has records like that. Also they all use 'live.com' suffix as this is pre-defined.

Comment: @ Polynomial  the CI "update" function could work potentially, but I only found ways to update the table using an array, which I currently dont have.

Answer (score 0):

If this is existing data in your database you should query the id from the associated row and pass that within your update function.

If you are trying to update a single row in your db use the update function

[link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

In your controller:

```
$data = array('id' => $id, 'email' => $to_email);
```

In your model

```
function update_email() {     
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('mytable', $data);
}
```

If you are trying to update multiple rows in your db at the same time, use the update batch function

In your controller, within the foreach loop:

```
$data[] = array('id' => $id, 'email' => $to_email);
```

In your model

```
function update_email_batch() {
    $this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'id'); 
}
```